# Katalon - not able to read SVG

Tags: xpath, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I tried to capture SVG object but Katalon program is not able to do it. I was looking for on the internet how to do it but already hours passed and I still get nowhere. Can you write me the xpath for this last object ` Deale: Przypisania? Here is the code. The screenshot is in the good resolution, just click the photo. Thanks for help

Here is the code:

```
<div id=‘mainPanel’>
    <span id=‘ChartLabel’>
        <div class=’highchairs-container’ id=‘highchairs-0’>
            <svg>
                <g class=‘highcharts-grid’></g>
                <g class=‘highcharts-grid’></g>
                <g class=‘highcharts-axis’></g>
                <g class=‘highcharts-axis’></g>
                <g class=‘highcharts-series-group’></g>
                <g class=‘highcharts-button’></g>
                <text class=‘highcharts-title’>
                    <tspan>Deale: Przypisania</tspan>
                </text>
                <g class=‘highcharts-legend’></g>
                <g class=‘highcharts-axis-labels highchairs-taxis-labels’></g>
                <g class=‘highcharts-grid axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels’></g>
                <g class=‘highcharts-tooltip’></g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </span> 
</div>
```

I have to get to this middle element Deale: Przypisania, how can I do it ?

Comment: Don't post screen captures of code. Post code. Make it easy for us to help you. Nobody wants to transcribe code from a screenshot.

Comment: Also, what is the criteria for selecting that `<tspan>` element? Is it that it's the last `<tspan>` in the `<svg>`, or that it contains the text "Deale: Przypisania",  or something else?

Comment: I have fixed it mate.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an example to locate  element at https://github.com/katalon-studio-samples/katalon-demo-project.

The example is as in the attached image [image]

Comment: what was your locator?